# iOS Format Background

Tags: ios, format

I am creating a simple quote app as a learning experience and need to format it to look better.

[image]

I am trying to make the background have a "white square" where the text is and make the text black. Just like the Twitter app has when you click on a tweet.

What is the best way to do this and what should I start with?

I know it is very simple, I'm only 15 and am trying to learn iOS. As you can see I have a server and have the app up and running, just want to format before I call it complete. Thanks! :)

-Henry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on how you created the label that displays your text, but you can do this very easily:

If you created your UI in a Storyboard / XIB file in XCode: assuming you dragged out a `UILabel` or `UITextView`, you can use the  Attributes Inspector to set the text color and the background color (in the *View* section) of the element holding the text.

If you created the label (or text view) in code, you can set the `textColor` property and the `backgroundColor` properties programmatically.